# How to capture single process and graph it to cacti?

Tags: linux, cacti

Is there any way that I can get CPU usage or memory usage for single process and graph it to cacti ?

Comment: It's better to use nagios, cacti used to bandwidth monitoring.

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nagios-on-debian-lenny-and-monitoring-a-debian-lenny-server

Comment: It's possible with cacti: http://forums.cacti.net/about11615.html Implementing it may need a lot of configuration depending on your system's setup, but in the end you'll get what you want.